# Azure Logic Apps not able to establish a connection

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm following the next tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-twitter-email. I had some problems with connecting to Twitter in Chrome, switched to Edge and was able to make the connection.

However for the sentiment analysis, created earlier in the tutorial, I'm constantly getting, in both browsers, the messages

> Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again.

I thought first that it would take a while before the service would kick in gear so I took the same Key1 and went to the [API overview](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c9) from where people can test the service after providing the key. And that worked.

So I'm wondering on how to continue or how to solve the connection problem as the analysis service key works out.

Comment: I got through it. Deleted all resources and put text analytics in West US vs West Europe. I'll try to repro it later on to see if that's the culprit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the time of writing this answer only cognitive accounts deployed into West US region are supported with the logic apps connector. However we are aware that cognitive services recently rolled out a number of new regions for text analytics, and are currently deploying the fix to support other regions. By the end of this week any region should be supported.  For now, the workaround is likely best approach (deploy a West US-based cognitive service account).

Comment: I wish that their tutorials had this noted.  I just did the tutorial and had the issue until I moved my cognitive service to West US from East US.

Comment: It is supported now since that comment was posted. You just need to be sure you paste in the URL endpoint of the cognitive service when creating the connection.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to login with Chrome.
Edge resolved this case and my resources are deployed in North Europe.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

> Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again+text analytics+logic app

when trying establish connection with Text Analytics Cognitive Service from Logic Apps.

I had deleted Text Analytics API and Recreated in Wets US Region and its working fine.